# How to count pixels in image with different multipliers according to height?

Tags: r, pixel, imagemagick-convert

I've made a series of images for each country in the world, where the pixel color means a specific vegetation cover. The original vegetation raster is from [GLC2000 project](http://forobs.jrc.ec.europa.eu/products/glc2000/products.php). The country boundaries from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip).

I tried using ImageMagick (in Debian) to count the pixels for each image:

```
for map in *.png; do convert $map -format %c histogram:info:hist/$map.txt; done
```

But there's a problem: the pixels at high latitudes are deformed, and thus should be multiplied by the cosine of the latitude, so their real area would be counted. I like ImageMagick because it's much faster than, say, R (my alternative). Can I do this using it? Or is there any other practical solution? I'm writing a script in R right now, but I see it will take a long time (235 countries).

Comment: Perhaps use Imagemagick -fx to distort the image first to conform to your cosine requirements. Since latitude is y, you are only distorting in one dimension. Thus it should not take too long to process.

Comment: @fmw42 Can you provide an example? The manual only says `-fx expression       apply mathematical expression to an image channel(s)`. Also, how can this be precise? There's no such thing as a "fraction of a pixel", is there?

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, if you have only a few colors, you can process color by color. You could convert the image so that the color in question is white and all the rest are black. Then average to one row so that the average is in the range 0 to 1 (divide the actual average by the max value of the color -- 255). Then the average of the pixel for a row multiplied by the width of the row gives you the count. So if you average to one column and multiply the column values by the cos(lat), that would tell you the counts for that color by lat. Then you would do the same for the next color.

Here is an example image of an 11x11 45 deg gradient colored with 3 colors created in Imagemagick.

```
convert -size 11x11 -define gradient:angle=45 gradient: -interpolate nearest-neighbor \( -size 1x1 xc:red xc:green1 xc:blue +append \) -clut img.png
```

[image]

I can get the average of the green1 color by row in the range 0 to 255 by the following:

```
convert img.png -fill white -opaque green1 -fill black +opaque white +write color.png -scale 1x! -type grayscale txt: | sed -n 's/^.*gray[(]\(.*\)[)]/\1/p'

139
162
185
209
232
255
232
209
185
162
139
```

Here is the binary mask image that was created before scaling to one column to produce the averages:

[image]

I can then change the values to the range 0 to 1 by dividing by 255 and then multiply by the width to get the count (bash unix syntax) by:

```
wd=`convert -ping img.png -format "%w" info:`
echo "$wd"
arr=(`convert img.png -fill white -opaque green1 -fill black +opaque white +write color.png -scale 1x! -type grayscale txt: | sed -n 's/^.*gray[(]\(.*\)[)]/\1/p'`) 
num=${#arr[*]}
echo "num=$num"
echo "${arr[*]}"
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
convert xc: -format "%[fx:$wd*${arr[$i]}/255)]\n" info:
done

5.99608
6.98824
7.98039
9.01569
10.0078
11
10.0078
9.01569
7.98039
6.98824
5.99608
```

If the top row corresponds is converted to a value of y=1, the center row to a value of y=0 and the bottom to a value of y=1 again, then taking the cos(y*pi/4)*count should do what you want assuming the center is at the equator and the top and bottom are at 45 deg latitude. I think the following might do that.

```
wd=`convert -ping img.png -format "%w" info:`
echo "$wd"
arr=(`convert img.png -fill white -opaque green1 -fill black +opaque white +write color.png -scale 1x! -type grayscale txt: | sed -n 's/^.*gray[(]\(.*\)[)]/\1/p'`) 
num=${#arr[*]}
echo "num=$num"
echo "${arr[*]}"
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
convert xc: -format "%[fx:cos((pi/4)*abs(($i-($num-1)/2))/(($num-1)/2)))*$wd*${arr[$i]}/255)]\n" info:
done

4.23987
5.6536
7.11058
8.57443
9.88463
11
9.88463
8.57443
7.11058
5.6536
4.23987
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not trying it. When I saw it, my algorithm had already finished running.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue, for higher latitudes you need to stretch out the width of the image so that you get more counts to correct for the type of projection. That is, higher latitudes are compressed in width in your graphs. So you want to stretch out the width at the top and bottom of your image so that when you get your histograms, you see more of each color coming from the higher latitudes. If this is correct, then in Imagemagick, you can distort the image as follows to do that according to a cosine function.

Assume that the lena image corresponds to being centered on the equator and goes up and down 45 degs (pi/4 radians).

[image]

```
convert lena.png -virtual-pixel none -fx "lat=(pi/4)*(j-h/2)/(h/2); u.p{cos(lat)*i,j}" tmp.png
```

[image]

So here the vertical center should not be distorted, but as you go higher or lower the data is stretch over more pixels.

Is this what you need?

If you need to keep colors from blending (due to the fractional pixel interpolation, then add -interpolate nearestneighbor.

```
convert lena.png -virtual-pixel none -interpolate nearestneighbor -fx "lat=(pi/4)*(j-h/2)/(h/2); u.p{cos(lat)*i,j}" tmp2.png
```

[image]

Comment: Actually it's the opposite: in high latitudes pixels have a smaller area. In the Poles, the area would be zero. So `area = (pixel count)*cos(latitude)`. I would have to shrink the image at high latitudes, that's why I asked about the precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the histogram in Imagemagick as text. Then script to extract the counts as an array. Then loop over the array and compute the cos(lat)*array_value as a function of the array indices. For example, here I make a simple 3 color image with 10x10 patches of each color, so that the counts should be 100,100,100. I then loop over the array and correct for the latitude assuming the center of the image is at the equator and the top and bottom colors are at 45 deg latitude. Unix syntax.

```
arr=(`convert -size 10x10 xc:red xc:green1 xc:blue -format "%c" histogram:info: | sed 's/^[ ]*//' | cut -d:  -f1`) 
num=${#arr[*]}
echo "num=$num"
echo "${arr[*]}"
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
im6912 convert xc: -format "%[fx:cos((pi/4)*abs($i-($num-1)/2))/(($num-1)/2)))*${arr[$i]}]\n" info:
done
```

The results are:

```
70.7107
100
70.7107
```

The sed 's/^[ ]*//' removes leading spaces from the text histogram. And the cut -d:  -f1 extracts just the count from each line of the histogram text output.

($num-1)/2 is the center line. So I am converting the line index that ranges from 0 to 2 into one that goes from -1 to 1, were 0 is the center.

Comment: This won't work, since I don't know (in your example) if the reds are closer to Equator or not. All I have is the total of reds, not the position of each one (so I could compute the real area correctly).

Comment: Well then why do you create a histogram?  You could do a histogram on each row of your input image and multiply each histogram by your cos(lat) as I did above. But that might be slow to do it row by row. But I do not see what alternative you have. Perhaps I misunderstand your concept. If so, please explain more clearly.

Comment: It's a land cover map. I want to know how many square kilometers of each country are forests, deserts, cities, etc. Maybe the row by row thing work, though I'm better at R (it's on letter "i" right now). I'm going to sleep. When I wake up tomorrow, it'll probably be solved.

Comment: See my new answer

Answer (score 0):

I used R to solve it, which is very slow (I left it running from one day to the next), but at least it was easier for me to understand what was going on. The solution from @fmw42 is probably faster, but I didn't even tried it, because mine had already finished running when I saw it.

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(png)
setwd('~/R/GLC2000/paises')
pa <- readOGR('../../shp/ne_10m_admin_0_countries','ne_10m_admin_0_countries')
GLCcolors <- c('#000000','#006400','#009600','#afff63','#8b4513','#cd7f60','#8cbe00','#7896ff',
               '#0047c8','#00e600','#ff7700','#ffb300','#ffea9e','#decaa1','#009696','#ffe0e5',
               '#ff75e8','#ca8aff','#b4b4b4','#8ae3ff','#f0f0f0','#ff0000','#ffffff')
d <- matrix(0,1,24)
d <- as.data.frame(d)
colnames(d) <- c('ISO3',GLCcolors)
for (p in list.files(pattern='*.png')) {
  pImg <- readPNG(p)
  p <- substr(p,1,3)
  pb <- grep(p,pa$ISO_A3)
  ext <- extent(pa[pb,])
  pI <- nrow(d)+1
  d[pI,1] <- p
  d[pI,2:24] <- 0
  for (h in 1:nrow(pImg)) {
    lat <- ext@ymax - h*(ext@ymax-ext@ymin)/nrow(pImg)
    co <- cos(pi*lat/180)
    for (w in 1:ncol(pImg)) {
      pix <- pImg[h,w,]
      if (sum(pix) == 0) {
        d[pI,2] = d[pI,2] + co
      } else {
        pixCor <- paste0('#',
                         format(as.hexmode(pix[1]*255),2),
                         format(as.hexmode(pix[2]*255),2),
                         format(as.hexmode(pix[3]*255),2))
        if (length(grep(pixCor,colnames(d),fixed=T)) == 1) {
          d[pI,grep(pixCor,colnames(d),fixed=T)] = d[pI,grep(pixCor,colnames(d),fixed=T)] + co
        } else {
          print(paste0('ERROR: color not found = ',pixCor,' (',p,' w=',w,' h=',h,')'))
        }
      }
    }
    if (h %% 100 == 0) {
      print(paste0(p,' ',h,'/',nrow(pImg)))
      flush.console()
    }
  }
}
write.table(d,'../countries.txt',quote=F,sep='\t',na='',row.names=F)
```

Comment: Worth noting that magick is available in R: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html

Comment: @zacdav That's awesome! Thank you!